# JavaScript Stop interval function

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval

```js
function setsTime(time, state){
 var idsc = document.getElementById("scount");
 var intervalId = null;
 if(time != '-1' && state == true){
  var totalSeconds = time;
  intervalId = setInterval(setTime, 1000);

  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    idsc.innerHTML = "00" + ":" + pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60)) + ":" + pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  }

  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
 }else{
  console.log("stopppppping setsTime()");
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  idsc.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
  return;
 }
}
```

When this function is executed for counting, everything works. But if I enter the else loop to stop the function so that the counter does not countert. Counterthe just continue the counter... :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `setsTime` a new interval and a new `intervalId` will be created. When you call `setsTime` to kill the previous interval, you actually create a new one and kill that. To solve that, just declare the `intervalId` outside of the function, so that multiple calls work with the same interval.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score -1):

Move intervalId out of the function.

Comment: (I love getting a downvote for the same answer, which I supplied first :/ )